# How to pass promise value into a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a piece of angular code here below.

I need to pass a value i get from a promise where it says `**value**` in the code

Here is my promise below

```
Auth.loggedInUser().then(function (user){
  return user.id
});
```

Below is angular code

```
.run(['$rootScope', 'ngCart','ngCartItem', 'stores', function ($rootScope, ngCart, ngCartItem, stores) {

    $rootScope.$on('ngShoppingCart:changed', function(){
        ngCart.$save();
    });

    if (angular.isObject(stores.get(**value**))) {
        ngCart.$restore(stores.get(**value**));

    } else {
        ngCart.init();
    }

}])
```

How can i pass what is returned (the value) in the async function up above into where it says **value** in the angular code? Not sure of the proper method.

Comment: Got it the below works, but what about something like this.

`this.empty = function () {

            $rootScope.$broadcast('ngShoppingCart:change', {});
            this.$cart.items = [];


            Auth.loggedInUser().then(function(user) {

              $window.localStorage.removeTheItem(user.id);

            });


        };`

I get errors such as `TyppeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will work

```
.run(['$rootScope', 'ngCart','ngCartItem', 'stores', function ($rootScope, ngCart, ngCartItem, stores) {

    $rootScope.$on('ngShoppingCart:changed', function(){
        ngCart.$save();
    });
    Auth.loggedInUser().then(function (user){
        if (angular.isObject(stores.get(user.id))) {
            ngCart.$restore(stores.get(user.id));

        } else {
            ngCart.init();
        }
    }); 

}])
```

Comment: Got it that works! But i have another one that doesnt work i posted in addition above

Comment: the above works, but what about something like this. `this.empty = function () { $rootScope.$broadcast('ngShoppingCart:change', {}); this.$cart.items = []; Auth.loggedInUser().then(function(user) { $window.localStorage.removeTheItem(user.id); }); };` I get errors such as `TyppeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined`

Comment: that would suggest `this.$cart` is undefined - nothing to do with Promises

Comment: It only happens when i encapsulate the function in that promise the original i psoted above.

Comment: I keep getting a slew of errors like this after injecting it in the original code above.

Comment: Which makes me think im breaking all the scoping.

Comment: any stack trace in the error message to help you debug?

Comment: Really it just generates the same error but for many different objects once i inject that value

Answer (score 0):

Inject the auth service to run and use the regular expression inside the promise

```
.run(['$rootScope', 'ngCart', 'ngCartItem', 'stores', 'Auth', function($rootScope, ngCart, ngCartItem, stores, Auth) {

    $rootScope.$on('ngShoppingCart:changed', function() {
        ngCart.$save();
    }); 

    Auth.loggedInUser().then(function(user) {

        if (angular.isObject(stores.get(user.id))) {
            ngCart.$restore(stores.get(user.id));

        } else {
            ngCart.init();
        }
    });

}])
```